# get information from other table where id=id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

soo i have 2 tables.

> **train_information**
>   **user_train_information**

When somebody submits something in a form. it get put in the `train_information` table and looks like this:

[image: what it looks like after the form is submitted]

Now, when people are logged in and select the train from a selector. his happens in the database:

[image: when people select the train]

On a other page, i want the users to see a whole list of things they selected over the time. So i run a query: `SELECT * FROM user_train_information WHERE user_id=user_id;`

This shows me the table `user_train_information`
But is it posible to show the train_information where user_id = user_id ? because i want the user to show the trains he added.

EDIT:

What i have now:

```
function testingggg() {
        $sql = "SELECT *
FROM train_information
INNER JOIN user_train_information
ON train_information.train_id = user_train_information.train_id
WHERE user_train_information.user_id = user_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam("user_id", $_GET["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

And i call i here:

```
<?php
        $summary = $database->testingggg();
    ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($summary as $result){
        echo $result['train_name']; 
    }
?>
```

I get the error:

[image: error]

Comment: table `train_information`  has no column `user_id`!

Comment: Tru @Jens , but they both have the column train_id

Comment: So your question is a little bit misunderstanding.

Comment: The error message is about column ambiguity. Where two tables share a column name, you need to state which one you're selecting. This is good practice for all columns. Don't use "SELECT *" . However, while column ambiguity exists in your table, the actual error referenced is a failure to properly prepare the query. Take another look at PHP's PDO prepare syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i use query in such case and it works. In your case there ambiguity somewhere. Also make sure you have proper value in $_GET["user_id"]. Please check

```
   function testingggg() {
        $sql = "SELECT ti.train_name, ti.train_id, uti.user_id
                FROM train_information as ti
                JOIN user_train_information as uti
                ON ti.train_id = uti.train_id
                WHERE uti.user_id = :user_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":user_id", $_GET["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.train_id
     , t.country_id train_country_id
     , t.train_name
     , t.number_of_bogies
     , t.number_of_axles
     , t.wheel_diameter_min
     , t.wheel_diameter_max
     , u.user_row_id
     , u.user_id
     , u.country_id user_country_id
  FROM user_train_information u
  JOIN train_information t
    ON t.train_id = u.train_id
 WHERE u.user_id = :user_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You try this one.

```
    SELECT * FROM train_information INNER JOIN user_train_information 
     ON train_information.train_id = user_train_information.train_id
    WHERE user_train_information.user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: you can do that using INNER JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   train_information 
       INNER JOIN user_train_information 
               ON train_information.train_id = user_train_information.train_id 
WHERE  user_train_information.user_id = user_id;
```